# FormArray don't find my formControlName in an object

Tags: angular, forms

I don't know why but my placeholder work perfectly. So I can see the name of my music, but if I want to use my `formControleName` my error is : `Cannot find control with path: musics -> name`

This is my form :

```
this.musicsForm = new FormGroup({
   musics: new FormArray([
     new FormControl(new Music('Musique 1', null, null)),
     new FormControl(new Music('Musique 2', null, null)),
   ]),
 });
```

And my object is like that :

```
export class Music {
  _id: string;
  name: string;
  fileUrl: string;
  feat: string; // i don't use it right now
  index: number; // i don't use it right now

  constructor(name: string, fileUrl: string, feat: string, index?: number) {
    this.name = name;
    this.fileUrl = fileUrl;
    this.feat = feat;
    this.index = index;
  }
}
```

And this is my HTML :

```
 <form [formGroup]="musicsForm" cdkDropList class="col-md-11 px-0" (cdkDropListDropped)="drop($event)">
    <class="example-box" *ngFor="let m of musicsForm.get('musics').controls; let i = index" cdkDrag>
      <div class="item row my-4 w-100" [formGroupName]=i>
        ...
        <div class="col-md-4 mt-1">
          <input class="px-2 w-100" type="text" [placeholder]="m.value.name" formControlName="name" > // I think the bug is just here
        </div>
        ...
      </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Can you try using `formControlName="musics[0].name"`?

Comment: Thank you but I got an error, it's : "Cannot find control with name: 'musics[0].name'"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `formArray` is an array of type `formGroup`, so you need to add a `formGroupName` within your `ngfor` to bind each `formGroup` in your `formArray`. This should be placed on an HTML element which encapsulates the `formControl`s within (i.e. properties in your `formGroup`: `name`, `fileUrl`, etc. You also need to pass a `formGroup` to your `formGroupName`. In order to pass the entire `formGroup`, you need to be looping through each element in `musics.controls` not `musics.value`.

Now, since we are no longer looping over `musics.value`, you will not be able to access the `name` value in your `placeholder` using `m.name`. You should use `m.value.name` instead.

**Edit**: You will also need to update your component as you creating a `formControl` when you should be creating a `formGroup`. You can use `FormBuilder` since it lets you generate `formGroup` using the normal object syntax. It would be better to create your entire form using `FormBuilder` rather than a mix of both `FormBuilder` and manual `FormControl` instances (creating form using `new FormGroup`, `new FormControl`, etc.)

```
this.musicsForm = this.fb.group({
  musics: this.fb.array([
    this.fb.group(new Music('Musique 1', null, null)),
    this.fb.group(new Music('Musique 2', null, null)),
  ])
});
```

Here's how your HTML will now look.

```
<div cdkDropList class="col-md-11 px-0" (cdkDropListDropped)="drop($event)" formArrayName="musics">
  <div class="example-box" *ngFor="let m of musicsForm.get('musics').controls; let i = index" cdkDrag>
    <div class="item row my-4 w-100" [formGroupName]="i">
      <!-- Define all formControlNames within your formGroup within this div -->
      ...
      <div class="col-md-4 mt-1">
        <input class="px-2 w-100" type="text" [placeholder]="m.value.name" formControlName="name">
      </div>
      ...
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Check out this [example](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormArrayName) on how to implement `formArray` correctly

Comment: Thank you I think it's the better answer, but when you use [formGroupName]="i", is it for the name of my music ? Cause on the example in the link, the form have only one attribut. But me I got 3 attributs in my object

Comment: I think my my problem it's inside the formArrayName. My error right now is : Cannot find control with path: 'musics -> music 2'. I think the formArrayName should be musics.name but it not working

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, I was in a bit of a hurry when i answered your question. I've updated my answer. Hope that fixes your issue :)

Comment: Thank you, my error right now is: Cannot find control with path: '1 -> name'. Now my form is only for musicForm, and I think the problem it's my formArrayName, thank you so much for your help

Comment: I have updated my answer. For future reference, I'd suggest you provide a working example on StackBlitz or your preferred online code editor so that you will be able to receive a more speedy and apt response :)

Answer (score 0):

add this in:

```
<div class="example-box" *ngFor="let m of musics.value;let i = index" [formGroupName]="i" cdkDrag>
```

your form array is an array of groups, and their group name is the index in that array. You need to tell angular that you want the 'name' control, and at which index you want it.  right now you're just saying I want the 'name' control of the form array 'musics' which doesn't exist, it only exists at indexes.